# Using subfigure and creating two rows of figures?

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I am trying to get two rows with two figures in each row using subfigure, but I keep getting errors for this.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}[0.45\textwidth]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{long_pneumonic.jpg}
    \caption{Pre-vaccination susceptible and infected 
    population$\alpha=0.000015, \beta=0.0027, \delta=.002, \sigma=1/3, 
    \Delta=3/4, r=1/5$.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{long_pneumonic2.jpg}
    \caption{Transient loops of the infected and susceptible population 
    changes.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{long_pneumonic3.jpg}
    \caption{The population of susceptible individuals and infected 
    individuals over a period of 1500 days post-vaccination.
    $\alpha=0.000015, \beta=0.0027, \delta=.002, \sigma=1/3, \Delta=3/4, 
    r=1/5$.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{long_pneumonic4.jpg}
    \caption{[A graph showing the rise and decrease of pneumonic plague 
    victims leading to increasing amounts of infected with each recurrence 
    post-vaccination.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Graphs comparing and contrasting the same parameters examining the 
dynamics of the susceptible and infected populations pre and post 
vaccinations.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I suggest you start by replacing `\begin{subfigure}[0.45\textwidth]` with `\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}` in the first `subfigure` environment.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding some code at the top and bottom of the code block in order to make it compilable. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Doing that, it stops and tells me there is an error in that line

Comment: And what might that error be? (Sorry, my psychic skills are badly underdeveloped...)

Comment: ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.544  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
                                           
?

Comment: Real quick: do you use the `subcaption` or the `subfigure` package? (The latter is badly deprecated.)

Comment: @Mico If he gets "Missing number" error messages he uses the `subfigure` package.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt - Thanks! That's what I was beginning to suspect.

Comment: @IanLynch - Can you confirm that the error messages vanish if you stop loading the deprecated `subfigure` package and start loading the `subcaption` package?

Answer (score 8):

You wrote,

> I keep getting errors

You didn't mention *which errors* you are getting, but I can only assume that they are caused by the line

```
\begin{subfigure}[0.45\textwidth]
```

at the start of the first `subfigure` environment. Change this line to

```
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
```

i.e., replace the square brackets with curly braces, and the immediate problem should be fixed. (Note that the other three `\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}` directives are already correct.) By the way, I'm assuming that your documents loads the `subcaption` package, *not* the obsolete and deprecated `subfigure` package.

In addition to fixing the syntax error, you may also want to "spruce up" the appearance of the figure. E.g., increase the horizontal separation between the subfigures, increase the space between the two rows of subfigures, and switch from full justification to centering for the captions of the four subfigures.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=Centering}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{long_pneumonic.jpg}
    \caption{Pre-vaccination susceptible and infected population. $\alpha=0.000015$, $\beta=0.0027$, $\delta= 0.002$, $\sigma=1/3$, $\Delta=3/4$, $r=1/5$.}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\fill} % maximize horizontal separation
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{long_pneumonic2.jpg}
    \caption{Transient loops of the infected and susceptible population changes.}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip % more vertical separation
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{long_pneumonic3.jpg}
    \caption{The population of susceptible individuals and infected individuals over a period of 1500 days post-vaccination.
    $\alpha=0.000015$, $\beta=0.0027$, $\delta=0.002$, $\sigma=1/3$, $\Delta=3/4$, 
    $r=1/5$.}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\fill} % maximize horizontal separation
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{long_pneumonic4.jpg}
    \caption{A graph showing the rise and decrease of pneumonic plague victims leading to increasing amounts of infected with each recurrence post-vaccination.}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Graphs comparing and contrasting the same parameters examining the  dynamics of the susceptible and infected populations pre and post  vaccinations.}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```